# How to modify a JSON file using Python without losing comments in the file

Tags: python, json

I have a `settings.json` file full with useful comments (sometimes C-style and sometimes Python), and I'm programmatically modifying them with e.g. `json` library, but when I save the modified one I lose all the comments explaining the fields. Another inconvenience is losing the indentations and spacing therein.

Is there a 'neat' way of modifying the file programmatically?

Comment: json files could not possibly have comments and still be compliant json. so, it is not possible

Comment: Certainly not with the built-in `json` module, it (like JSON itself) doesn't support comments. It can pretty-print to the file though, so it's unclear what problem you've had there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So, you are saying it will have to be some messy text parsing solution?

Comment: Well maybe, or find a Python JSON library that _does_ support comments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, it is not possible to find json library which can support comments. if you permit C style comments, that is not json anymore, it is something else (json5, yaml, etc)

Comment: @mvp while technically correct, I'm sure there are "JSON-adjacent" libraries that support comments (and other extensions to strict JSON), although the OP may have to adapt to the syntax they do support. Indeed you've identified one below.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, no. any strict json parser will (and should!) fail to parse C style comments

Comment: Of course, one can put a dictionary mapping fields to explanations in the JSON, although that could be a bit kuldgy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard json files cannot possibly have comments and still be compliant json.

There is another format that was designed to overcome this problem: [json5](https://json5.org). It has libraries designed to keep json5 properties like comments intact - you can python library for it [here](https://pypi.org/project/json5).

Another approach is to keep using standard JSON but add `"doc"` fields for each JSON block in question. In this case, `doc` field(s) become data payload and will survive any transformation. For example, [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html) is using `doc` fields to document avro schema.

Comment: It parses jsons with C-style comments seamlessly, but the comments are gone. I'm starting to realize it is not possible to have them in json format.

Comment: One solution to have comments in json that I have seen often used is to add `"doc"` fields for each block in question. In this case, `doc` field becomes data payload and will survive any transformation. For example, [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html) is using doc fields for their schemas

Comment: Neat! I'll follow this, but I'll have to coerce existing files to this format.